# TFS Java SDK Error (NativeAuth - Error configuring native authentication library)

Tags: tfs, java-native-interface, aix, tfs-sdk

We are sending files to TFS using the [TFS Java SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere).
The files have been successfully sent until August 30 and the following error message occurs after August 30.
This problem occurred on [AIX Server](https://www.ibm.com/power/operating-systems/aix).
What should I check?

```
NativeAuth - Error configuring native authentication library
java.lang.UnsatifiedLinkError: com/microsoft/tfs/jni/internal/auth/NativeAuth.nativeAuthConfigure()J
    at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.auth.NativeAuth.<cinit>(NativeAuth.java:53)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:201)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.negotiate.NativeNegotiate.isAvailable(NativeNegotiate.java:52)
...
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue every time? Are you able to get files after August 30 only? What's the difference between the files before and after August 30?

Comment: thx for your reply. I can't any files because connection fail(NativeAuth).

Comment: Is the authentication changed on tfs server?

Comment: not chaned authentication. It's ok other server on same authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of API, you can try to run the [get command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092(v=vs.120).aspx) to retrieve files from TFS:

```
tf get
```

Comment: it will be return same result(NativeAuth Error). Because "tf" command uses same API.

Comment: @정석훈 Are you able to get the files after August 30 from Team Explorer Everywhere? Do you have the proper permission to access the files after August 30?

Comment: Yes. Only AIX Server has problem. 
The program was operated normally using TFS Java SDK from another OS. And Team Explorer also normally operated on Windows.

Comment: @정석훈 It seems your issue is related to AIX Server, not TFS sdk. Are you also able to get the files after August 30 from UI on AIX Server?

Comment: How can I get the files from UI? (it's AIX Server)

Comment: @정석훈 I don't have AIX server to reproduce your issue, but I found a similar case in MSDN:　https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1661154d-0765-46ad-b69b-ea3a0fbf215b/tf-and-aix-71?forum=tee. You may try the solution in this case to see whether it works for you.

Comment: @정석훈 "it will return same result" - maybe not.  I'm doing something very similar to you.  I have Team Explorer Everywhere successfully running on AIX and can execute `tf` commands, but the Java application I wrote that uses the TFS SDK on that same machine is getting the same error as you: "NativeAuth - Error configuring native authentication library
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError".